# Select query returns only registers with specific month and year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my MySql database with a column called date. 
This column archives dates in  YYYY-MM-DD format.

How can I select only registers with specific month and year.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date = '$MY_MONTH' and YEAR = '$MY_YEAR'
```

Comment: you can check this reference for any more questions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give a specific error? Please show what attempts you've made. From what it looks like you're asking, you're just asking how to make a select call, which has been answered on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL Functions are date() and year().

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE month(date) = '$MY_MONTH' and year(date) = '$MY_YEAR'
```